# result returns empty from codeigniter model

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a search page that contains four dropdowns and the values set in them is used to query the database. I have tested to be sure that the values are passed to the model, but the database is returning empty array. However, if I enter the values directly into the sql query in the model, it returns a result set. Below are my codes. Thanks in advance.

Controller

```
public function search(){

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('state', 'State', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('city', 'City', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('minPrice', 'Minimum Price', 'required');
    $this->form_validation->set_rules('maxPrice', 'Maximum Price', 'required');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) {

        $this->index();
    }
    else{

        $state      =   $this->input->post('state');
        $city       =   $this->input->post('city');
        $minPrice   =   $this->input->post('minPrice');
        $maxPrice   =   $this->input->post('maxPrice');

        $data['hostel_search'] = $this->Hostel_model->search_hostels($state, $city, $minPrice, $maxPrice);
        $this->load->view('_parts/header');
        $this->index_top();
        $this->load->view('search', $data);
        $this->load->view('_parts/footer');
    }
}
```

Model

```
public function search_hostels($state, $city, $minPrice, $maxPrice){


    $state = (int)$state;
    $city = (int)$city;
    $minPrice = (int)$minPrice;
    $maxPrice = (int)$maxPrice;

    $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM `hostels` WHERE `state_id`='$state' AND `city_id`='$city' AND `price` BETWEEN '$minPrice' AND '$maxPrice'");
    $this->db->from($this->table);
    $result = $query->result();
    return $result;

}
```

View

```
 <?php echo form_open('site/search'); ?>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa"><strong>State</strong></i></span>
      <select id="state" name="state" class="form-control" required>
                <option value="" selected>--Select State--</option>
        <?php foreach ($state_option as $state_id => $state) { ?>
          <option id="<?php echo $state_id; ?>" value="<?php echo $state_id; ?>"><?php echo $state; ?></option>
        <?php } ?>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa"><strong>City</strong></i></span>
        <select id="city" name="city" class="form-control" required>
                  <option id="" value="" selected>--Select City--</option>
              </select>
            </div>
            </div>


      <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa"><strong>Purpose</strong></i></span>
          <select name="purpose" class="form-control" required>
                    <option value="" selected>--Select Purpose--</option>
                    <option value="rent">Rent</option>
              <option value="let">Let</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            </div>

      <div class="col-sm-4">
            <div class="form-group input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa"><strong>Min Price</strong></i></span>
              <select name="minPrice" class="form-control" required>
                        <option value="" selected>--Select Price--</option>
                        <option value="5000">5000</option>
                    <option value="7000">7000</option>
                    <option value="8000">8000</option>
                    <option value="9000">9000</option>
                    <option value="10000">10000</option>
            </select>
            </div>
            </div>          

        <div class="col-sm-4 pull-center" >
        <button class="btn btn-block btn-info btn-md" type="submit" style="margin-bottom:20px; background-color:#06F; border-radius:5px; border:none; position: relative;" id="search"><i class="fa fa-search"></i>&nbsp;Search</button>
    </div>

    <div class="col-sm-4">
      <div class="form-group input-group">
      <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa"><strong>Max Price</strong></i></span>
              <select name="maxPrice" class="form-control" required>
                  <option value="" selected>--Select Price--</option>
                  <option value="50000">50000</option>
                  <option value="60000">60000</option>
                  <option value="70000">70000</option>
                  <option value="80000">80000</option>
                  <option value="100000">100000</option>
      </select>
      </div>
      </div>
      <?php echo form_close();?>
```

AM using this JavaScript to populate the city based on the value returned in the state id

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('#state').change(function(){
        $('#city').html('<option>Loading....</option>');
        var state = $('#state').val();
        if (state != "") {
          $.get("<?php echo base_url(); ?>site/dependent_dropdown/"+state).success(function(data){
              $('#city > option').remove();                
              data = JSON.parse(data);
              for(var i in data){
                $('#city').append("<option id='"+i+"' value='"+data+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>");
              }

          })
        }
      else{
        $('#city').html('<option>--Select City--</option>');
      }
      });

   });
```

And Pls don't worry about `$this->index_top()`. It's serving it's purpose.

Comment: add your view code as well

Comment: and what is this ` $this->index_top();` ??

Comment: @Abdulla, I have added the view.

Comment: Use `echo '<br>' . $this->db->last_query() . '<br>';` after `$result = $query->result();` in your model to see exactly what query is being sent to the database.

Comment: @Goose, here's the output ``SELECT * FROM `hostels` WHERE `state_id`=17 AND `city_id`=17 AND `price` BETWEEN 5000 AND 100000``. 
The exact values I entered via the view.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My JavaScript was the problem
I changed this line 
`$('#city').append("<option id='"+i+"' value='"+data+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>");`
to this
`$('#city').append("<option value='"+i+"'>"+data[i]+"</option>");`
Many thanks to @Goose, that debug syntax was the clue. I noticed that from my index page, the `$city_id` was returning `0`. But from the search page it fetched the appropriate value. Then firebug came to play and the rest is history.

If you found my question and answer helpful please vote it up.

Thanks y'all.